# delete an appended text using an appended button on jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <button id="btn_id">CLICK THE BUTTON</button> RESULTS:
        <div id="result"></div>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.4.4.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        $("#btn_id").click(function () {
            $("#result").append("<button type='button' id='btn_id2' class='close pull-right' aria-    hidden='true'>&times;<\/button>" + "<pre class='one'>Sample text<\/pre>");

            $("#btn_id").click(function () {
                $("#btn_id").remove();
                $(".one").empty();

            });
        });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

I'm having a problem on the above code. I'm trying to append text with a button on it. The button will be the one to trigger to remove the appended text. But what happening is I can't remove the appended text one by one. The first appended text with the button has only the capability to remove all the appended text. But what I wanted to happen is that, it should be one at a time even though that I clicked the "CLICK THE BUTTON" a number of times.

What I needed is the "CLICK THE BUTTON" to be clicked a number of times and it will produced an appended text with a close button on it. The close button will be the one to remove the appended text, only for that specific text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for something like this?

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LgAfC/2/)

JavaScript:

```
$("#btn_id").on('click', function(){
    $("#result").append("<div><button type='button' id='btn_id' class='close pull-right' aria-hidden='true'>&times;</button>"+"<pre>Sample text</pre></div>");
});

$(document).on('click', 'button.close', function(){        
    $(this).parent().remove();
});
```

HTML:

```
<button id="btn_id">CLICK THE BUTTON</button>
RESULTS: <div id="result"></div>
```

Comment: Damn man, I was doing an almost equal answer. Also, why use ```event.preventDefault()``` for this task?

Comment: Sorry for that ;) That's a bad habit I've, thanks for mentioning.

Comment: thanks for your help but it is not working just like what i needed. When you click the "CLICK THE BUTTON" button, it will append the text with the close button on it.. and when I click the close button, the appended text and the close button will also be remove..

Comment: Ehm it does exactly what you try to explain. Have you tried the example from jsfiddle?

Comment: THANKS!! BIG HELP!! haha.. At first it didn't work because I'm using an old version of jquery. Thanks again..